# Will demand for data scientist decrease because of AYASDI?

Tags: data-mining, bigdata

I am pursing Data Analyst course at Udacity. I came across this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Z73Wd2T1xE

Watching it lead me to wonder if [Ayasdi](http://www.ayasdi.com/) products would reduce the demand for data scientists. I wish to compete in Kaggle contests but after watching the video, I feel that many of those problems can be easily solved using their platform and that I will be at disadvantage since I do not have access to their tools. Also I feel such tools would reduce the need of experts in data sciences. Now I am worried if I should continue with Nano Degree in Data Analyst at Udacity.

Comment: I don't think many people are going to start by watching an hour+ long video. How about describing your fears in a bit more detail.

Comment: Good news: there are lots more tools like this.

Comment: A related discussion on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/datascience/comments/373lpg/data_science_and_automation/)

Comment: How can we tell this Q isn't simply advertising for that product?

Answer (score 6):

I will assume that you have not been working in statistics that long since you are talking about jumping ship because of a new software that's coming out. Let me give you a bit of reassurance:

For the past fifty or so years computers have been solving complex mathematical problems for statisticians and mathematicians, and now with the type of computing power we have today we are able to process terabytes of data per second and develop extremely sophisticated predictive models in a matter of seconds. Software has constantly evolved and constantly made people's lives easier. Has that changed the fact that we still need people to interpret the data? The model? The results? No, it hasn't.

However, you should know that when software comes out that eliminates a lot of the grunt work, well, you no longer need to employ undergrads/post-baccs to complete those grunt tasks. Now you can use a software to do it, and higher people of a stronger caliber to perform more complex sets of analyses. The more software evolves, the more training a data scientist will require before breaking into the field.

So you see, it's not that completing the nano degree alone will or will not give you a competitive edge in the data science job market, it's that this nano degree is *the first step* in your journey toward becoming a data scientist.

If anything, software like this should encourage all of us to hit the books and ensure that we're still up to date on our game. No amount of bangs and whistles will teach a computer judgement. Prediction? Yes. But not judgement. We don't have Skynet yet.